# Book searching in Pluripotential theory

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, harmonic-analysis, several-complex-variables

Can anyone **recommend** me a book on **pluripotential theory** with an intuitive approach? I have some course notes on that subject, but it's really abstract and theoretical. I want to understand why ***pluripotential/subharmonic/...*** were introduced and so on. My teacher wanted us to learn the book's Z.Blocki...

Ex: I don't understand :(

1/ Suppose that $u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R} $, a function $u$ is called *harmonic* if $u$ is continouns and $$u(x_0)=\dfrac{1}{V_n(B(x_0,r))}\int_{B(x_0,r)}u(x)\mathrm{d}V_n(x)$$.

2/ We have $u(x_0)=\dfrac{1}{\sigma(\partial B(x_0,r))}\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)}u(x)\mathrm{d}\sigma(x)$.

Your comments & suggestions are ALWAYS appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you study harmonic functions in a more physical context first. I take it that pluripotential theory is a massive generalization of complex analysis and harmonic function theory, so it might make more sense if you understand the easier subjects that it generalizes.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I don't think you will be able to find something really "intuitive". Pluripotential theory is rather theoretical and also a highly specialist field. You should already have a solid background in classical potential theory and measure theory before you attempt to learn pluripotential theory.

A very good introduction to **classical potential theory** is

- Ransford, *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane*. This will provide you with the background knowledge you need to appreciate and understand the subtlelties when you generalize the concepts to (the nonlinear) pluripotential setting.

That said, I would suggest that you start with the material in

- Krantz, *Function theory in several complex variables*.

It only covers the very basics, but is very readable and a gentle introduction.

For more throrough treatments, have a look at

- Klimek, *Pluripotential theory*. This was the first book published on the subject and is a little dated.
- The [lecture notes by](http://gamma.im.uj.edu.pl/~blocki/publ/ln/wykl.pdf) Błocki are very good.
- I haven't read them myself, but the [lecture notes](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~fbracci/download/pluripotential.pdf) by Bracci and Trapani also look good.
- There is also a lot of material on pluripotential theory in [Demailly's excellent book on complex analytic methods in algebraic geometry](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf&ei=-KAZUt_KPIuu4QS0lIDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNFnfR89_SkLNSZsUPYBJjXMyL7kqQ&sig2=E8ya3Nxex5IPdyiwbORShw&bvm=bv.51156542,d.bGE).

It may also be a good idea to read some of the old original research papers, for example I recommend

- E. Bedford, B. A. Taylor, *The Dirichlet problem for a complex Monge-Ampère
  equation*. Invent. Math. 37 (1976), 1-44.
- J. Siciak, *On some extremal functions and their applications in the theory of analytic functions of several complex variables*. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 105 (1962), 322-357.
- J. Siciak, *Extremal plurisubharmonic functions*, Ann. Pol. Math. 39 (1981), 175-211.

There are lots of other papers I could recommend if I know what particular areas you are interested in.

Comment: Wow! **mrf** I still miss you. In my mind, you are the one who helped me a lot. Last time I had had a vacation, how are you? **mrf** :)
In the future, I am looking forward to your help. If it does not mean that I annoy you. Hihi

Comment: @kimtahe6 Welcome back. Maybe this time around you will learn how to vote on questions and answers you find useful, as well as accepting answers to your own questions.

Comment: The upvote is mine, by the way. The Ransford book is excellent and has a lot of nice tricks in it. I wish I had time to finish reading it...